# How to specify initial ref's data structure in Firebase and React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All:

I wonder if I use firebase in react component `componentDidMount()` like:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var newdata = this.database.ref("not_exist_field")
}
```

I wonder how can I tell firebase what data type I want that field be( for example, an array or an Object)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase references will accept any data type, and will take on the data type you provide when it's first set.  So, for example, if you want it to be a string, do this:

```
this.database.ref("not_exist_field").set("I'm a string now!")
```

If you want it to be an object, do this:

```
this.database.ref("not_exist_field").set({ name: "Thing", age: 3 })
```

And so on, and so forth.  If you need type information, you'll have to provide it yourself.  You can always do something like this:

```
this.databse.ref("not_exist_field").set([
  { key: "field_1", type: "string", value: "hello" },
  { key: "field_2", type: "object", value: { name: "Thing", age: 3 } },
  { key: "field_3", type: "number", value: 7 },
])
```

I don't see that this question has anything specifically to do with React, but perhaps I'm missing something?